# Battery Voltage Monitor LTspice

Tags: led, simulation, ltspice

I'm a beginner at using LTpice. I want to build a circuit that monitors the voltage level of a battery. This is an ideal circuit to monitor the Voltage level in 12-volt Lead Acid batteries used in Inverters. I've already built the circuit, though I"m not sure if I have it right and I'm also not sure how to run it. The goal is to have one LED turn on and the other turn off for a voltage of 13.5V and 10V I have a description of the desired circuit below: 
This is an ideal circuit to monitor the Voltage level in 12-volt Lead Acid batteries used in Inverters. For the perfect operation of Inverters, the battery voltage should be between 12 and 13.5 volts. A fully charged battery shows 13.5 volts. If the voltage reduces below 10 volts, the Inverter will not give back up. Moreover, if the Inverter is continuously charging without attaining 13.5 volts, it indicates that the battery is not accepting and holding charge.

The circuit is too simple and uses only a few components. It shows three indications.

If the battery has 13.5 volts, Green half of the bicolor LED lights.
If the battery has 12 volts(Normal) LED will be Off
If the battery voltage reduces below 10 volts, Red half of bicolour LED lights.

Any information would be appreciated. Thank you[image]

Comment: So you built it in a simulator, and did not simulate it?

Comment: I did simulate it, but I didn't get the expected result

Comment: So what did you expect, and how did it work? Add the info to the question. Also, remember to ask a question.

Comment: You need to reverse the polarity of the supply (or of the opamp). Also, what's the purpose of `D1`?